# updating package repository skipping ngcp ppa generation as variable NGCP_PPA is not set in Sipwise

Tags: debian, sip, voip

Hello Everyone,
           I have install debian 8 linux OS.Now I want to install ncgp for sip services.I will follow given toturial:
for install debian os:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FOm2CvZ6aDo

for install ngcp configuration:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bcZ4rc0VA4c
https://www.sipwise.org/doc/2.5/spce/ar01s02.html

according to vedio toturial IP configuration is not present in our configuration.but install successfully.

when i install ncgp then following command perform perfectly.

```
PKG=ngcp-installer-latest.deb
wget http://deb.sipwise.com/spce/${PKG}
dpkg -i ${PKG}
```

but when we run following command:

ngcp-installer

Then it is stop then show skipping point warning as below:
"updating package repository skipping ngcp ppa generation as variable NGCP_PPA is not set"

how can i solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://www.sipwise.org/doc/mr3.8.4/spce/):

> You need to install Debian Wheezy (v7) 64-bit on the server. A basic installation without any additional task selection (like Desktop System, Web Server etc.) is sufficient.

There's also the public mailing list for [sipwise](http://lists.sipwise.com/listinfo/spce-user)